# Moving Java (Spring, Hibernate, MySql) project from Windows to Debian

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, mysql-error-1075

I am writing project on Windows (IntelliJIdea), and all OK. It compiles, and runs. But when I try to run on Debian(GNU/Linux 5.0), I have

`SEVERE: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

     [java] 30.11.2010 15:39:04 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings

     [java] WARNING: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

     [java] java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)

     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)

     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)

     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)`

I use such Spring config:

```
<bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="mydb"/>
    <property name="password" value="Fallout_3"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>entities/ClientPrices.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>entities/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>entities/Provider.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>entities/MessageQueue.hbm.xml</value>
            <value> hibernate/SimpleEntity.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
            hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
        </value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add permission to root for localhost in your mysql server

execute :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

on your mysql console.

- [Resource](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: Is it usefull? I am using mydb user.

Comment: @user266163 you need to execute this from mysql console